# django-tables2 edit yesno parameter for all BooleanColumn

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I have a table.py where I would like to change the icons for True and False values of each BooleanColumn. I know that it can be modified by the yesno paramter of BooleanColumn, but I do not know how to override the default for all BooleanColumns. Here is the Code of tables.py (aacsb, amba, equis, mba, bsc, msc and doubedegree are BooleanFields):

```
from django_tables2 import Column, Table
from manager.models import Partner


class PartnerTable(Table):

    country_name = Column(accessor='country.name', verbose_name='Country')
    region_name = Column(accessor='country.region.name', verbose_name='Region')

    class Meta:
        model = Partner
        fields = ('name',
                  'country_name',
                  'region_name',
                  'website',
                  'aacsb',
                  'amba',
                  'equis',
                  'mba',
                  'bsc',
                  'msc',
                  'doubledegree',
                  )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) So you can simply override `yesno` which default value is "✔,✘" (it is just `str`):

```
some_name = BooleanColumn(yesno='1,2')
```

or remove text:

```
some_name = BooleanColumn(yesno=',')
```

2) Using `css` you can specify custom images (don't forget set `yesno=','`):

```
span.true {
    background: url(../img/true.gif) top center no-repeat;
}

span.false {
    background: url(../img/false.gif) top center no-repeat;
}
```

3) Specify some extra attrs to `span` (but **don't** specify `class` !):

```
some_name = BooleanColumn(attrs={'span': {'style': 'color:blue'}})
```

4) If for some reasons you want change default class setting behaviour (`true` or `false`) - you should override `BooleanColumn` and it's method `render`

```
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django_tables2.utils import AttributeDict


class CustomBooleanColumn(BooleanColumn):
    def render(self, value):
        value = bool(value)
        text = self.yesno[int(not value)]
        html = '<span %s>%s</span>'

        class_name = 'some_class_false'
        if value:
            class_name = 'some_class_true'
        attrs = {'class': 'class_name'}

        attrs.update(self.attrs.get('span', {}))

        return mark_safe(html % (AttributeDict(attrs).as_html(), escape(text)))
```

And override your field

```
some_name = CustomBooleanColumn(yesno=',')
```

Comment: Yes you are right, `(''.split(',') if isinstance('', str) else tuple('')) == ['']` so `[''][int(not True)] == ''` but  `[''][int(not False)] == IndexError`

Answer (score 0):

Here is full code now, thanks to madzohan's answer. Note that I used django-bootstrap3 so that i can use the bootstrap icons:

```
from django_tables2 import BooleanColumn, Column, Table
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django_tables2.utils import AttributeDict
from manager.models import Partner


class BootstrapBooleanColumn(BooleanColumn):
    def __init__(self, null=False, **kwargs):
        if null:
            kwargs["empty_values"] = ()
        super(BooleanColumn, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def render(self, value):
        value = bool(value)
        html = "<span %s></span>"

        class_name = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
        if value:
            class_name = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
        attrs = {'class': class_name}

        attrs.update(self.attrs.get('span', {}))

        return mark_safe(html % (AttributeDict(attrs).as_html()))


class PartnerTable(Table):
    country_name = Column(accessor='country.name', verbose_name='Country')
    region_name = Column(accessor='country.region.name', verbose_name='Region')
    aacsb = BootstrapBooleanColumn()
    amba = BootstrapBooleanColumn()
    equis = BootstrapBooleanColumn()
    mba = BootstrapBooleanColumn()
    bsc = BootstrapBooleanColumn()
    msc = BootstrapBooleanColumn()
    doubledegree = BootstrapBooleanColumn()

    class Meta:
        model = Partner
        fields = ('name',
                  'country_name',
                  'region_name',
                  'website',
                  'aacsb',
                  'amba',
                  'equis',
                  'mba',
                  'bsc',
                  'msc',
                  'doubledegree',
                  )
```

Comment: Why did you keep `yesno` if you don't use it? just override `__init__` method and remove it